# Javascript foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, repeater

I have a question about repeater objects in asp.net.

In html and script parts I have this code below.

```js
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(MyEdit);

function MyEdit() {
  jQuery(function($) {

    //editables on first profile page
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
    $.fn.editableform.loading = "<div class='editableform-loading'><i class='ace-icon fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x light-blue'></i></div>";
    $.fn.editableform.buttons = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info editable-submit"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"></i></button>' +
      '<button type="button" class="btn editable-cancel"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i></button>'
    //editables 
    //text editable
    $('#rptQuestionTitle')
      .editable({
        type: 'text',
        name: 'username'
      });
    $('#rptQuestionDescription')
      .editable({
        type: 'text',
        name: 'username'
      });

  });
}
MyEdit();
```

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="rptQuestionRepeater" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 50px">No</th>
        <th style="width: 200px; height: auto">Question</th>
        <th style="width: 400px; height: auto">Description</th>
      </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%#Eval("Sort")%>
      </td>
      <td><span class="editable editable-click" runat="server" id="rptQuestionTitle"><%#Eval("Text") %></span></td>
      <td><span class="editable editable-click" runat="server" id="rptQuestionDescription"><%#Eval("Description") %></span></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am trying to do an editable table. I have to be able to edit each row. But as you can see my script codes, I can only assign id's to be editable. I need to have class editable. 
In ASP.NET repeater each element has different Id's thanks to the repeater. My edit JS code works just for one row because I've assigned the id's by myself as in the JS and Repeater.
But after second row the ID's are automatically changed into something like repeater's counter.

So my real question is, apart from editing with equal ID's in the script, how can I edit my rows in repeater which they will have different ID's. I think I need to use foreach() but not sure how to do it.

I want to have my all rows editable when I just type their class ".editable" or I can create another class, it doesn't really matter. All I want is an ID free solution.

Comment: Which editable library are you using? If it's been created properly it should handle any selector, so a class would work fine in theory. It should loop through all Element instances and instantiate the library on each of them separately. If it can't even do that then I'd suggest finding a better table editor library.

Comment: It is not looping through all elements. It is just looking for id's which match with the id's inside script. I want to edit all elements no matter their Id. I need to edit all spans which has "editable" class in it. I need an Id free solution.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm saying. Use classes.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Just writing <span class="editable"></span> isn't enough. I need to set that JS code for every span (or every element, doesn't matter) if they are assigned class="editable" behave the same as in the code above (which the behaviour assigned to their id's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to run your code at the snippet. Bu try using `$('.editable')` instead of the id `$('#rptQuestionTitle')`. If the plugins is ready to receive an array and work with it, it'll work.

Comment: I was hurried toward to this page to delete that question. Because I solved the problem as you did. But I'm caught.. Now I want to knock my head to the wall because I asked something that simple.. :D Thanks anyways. Sorry I can't rep you up. Because my rep is below 15..

Comment: no prop. stackoverflow was made to solve problems :)